# How to edit code while debugging is happening in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Im using Eclipse Luna.

I want to edit some code in the middle while i debug the code. That is, I connected to a server and try to debug code,So at some point i want to edit the code make it to run.

Is that possible in Eclipse? I think this can be done in IDEA..Not sure how can i do that in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely edit the code while debugging, although that would not have any effects on the currently debugged process. You have to relaunch the debug process to see the effects.

Comment: That means, i need to compile the code and again put that to server to see the output?

Comment: As far as I remember. At least that is what I remember doing when I used to work on servlets, jsps. If you have configured your server and program to be run from within Eclipse I'm guessing that should not be much of a problem.